# FSD files - can I delete them?

Tags: macos, office-365, space

These seem to take up loads of space.  Can I safely delete them or will it cause problems?

[image: here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are cache files for syncing changes between OneDrive for Business and/or Sharepoint shares.

Is it safe to delete?   Yes.

However, they'll just be recreated as you sync back and forth your OneDrive folder(s).

However, there's been a fix for this for some time now - make sure you update your OneDrive client and that you enable [Files-On-Demand](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-onedrive-files-on-demand-on-mac-529f6d53-e572-4922-a585-e7a318c135f0)